# Is there any way to import a contact list from Gmail into evite.com?

Tags: gmail, export

I want to send out an [Evite](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evite), and I have all of the email addresses in a Gmail contact list. I see I can import from Gmail by going through my contact list, but is there a way to select a Gmail contact list and have it import all that at once?

Answer (score 1):

In Gmail you can export all your contacts by going to

- Contacts
- Click on *More*
- Select Export

This will export all your Gmail contacts into a CSV file, then in evite you can Import all contacts using that CVS file.

Comment: it doesn't look like Evite has a CSV import

Comment: @ooo Yes it does: http://www.evite.com/pages/addrbook/import/importCsvCreate.jsp

Comment: not the "new" evite: http://getsatisfaction.com/evite/topics/importing_contacts_from_a_csv_file

Answer (score 0):

You can export a Gmail contact list, and then import it from a [CSV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) file or whatever into Evite.

Try to follow the directs on [this](http://www.evite.com/pages/create/demo.jsp) page. It seems designed to do what you want.

Comment: it doesn't look like Evite has a CSV import

Comment: @ooo edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the new evite now supports importing contacts as per [this post](http://evite.desk.com/customer/portal/articles/544633-how-do-i-import-my-yahoo-hotmail-or-gmail-contacts-)

Answer (score 0):

You can export the emails as a CSV file.  You can't directly import the CSV file into Evite.  However you CAN open the CSV file in Excel, then copy and paste the column of emails from Excel into Evite.